# L-function of Hilbert modular forms of non-parallel weight

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, l-functions

I found that in many literature, they only define the L-function of Hilbert modular forms of parallel weight. Can we define the following L-function:
\begin{equation}
L(f;s_1,\cdots,s_n)=\int_0^{i\infty}\cdots\int_0^{i\infty}f(\tau_1,\cdots,\tau_n)\tau_1^{s_1}\cdots\tau_n^{s_n}\frac{d\tau_1}{\tau_1}\cdots \frac{d\tau_n}{\tau_n}.
\end{equation}
I am wondering if there is any literature about it. If such definition is well-defined, then does it have the functional equation like
\begin{equation}
L(f;s_1,\cdots,s_n)=C\cdot L(f;k_1-s_1,\cdots,k_n-s_n)
\end{equation}
for some constant $C$ which doesn't depend on $f$?

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: L-functions are certainly defined for non-parallel-weight Hilbert modular forms. See e.g. this paper: https://www.jstor.org/stable/23525866?seq=1. However, they're still functions of a single variable $s$, not of $s_1, \dots, s_n$.